# wordcount: reducer python program throws ValueError

Tags: python, hadoop

I get this error whenever I try running Reducer python program in Hadoop system. The Mapper program is perfectly running though. Have given the same permissions as my Mapper program. Is there a syntax error?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reducer.py", line 13, in 
    word, count = line.split('\t', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

```
            #!/usr/bin/env python
            import sys

            # maps words to their counts
            word2count = {}

            # input comes from STDIN
            for line in sys.stdin:
                # remove leading and trailing whitespace
                line = line.strip()

                # parse the input we got from mapper.py
                word, count = line.split('\t', 1)
                # convert count (currently a string) to int
                try:
                    count = int(count)
                except ValueError:
                    continue

                try:
                    word2count[word] = word2count[word]+count
                except:
                    word2count[word] = count

            # write the tuples to stdout
            # Note: they are unsorted
            for word in word2count.keys():
                print '%s\t%s'% ( word, word2count[word] )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack` is thrown when you do a multi-assign with too few values on the right hand side.  So it looks like `line` has no `\t` in it, so `line.split('\t',1)` results in a single value, causing something like `word, count = ("foo",)`.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer in detail.

However, I solved the same issue I had when I removed some extra `print` I had added in the `mapper`. Probably it is related with how `print` works for `sys.stdin`.

I know probably you have already solved the issue now

Answer (score 0):

I changed `line.split('\t', 1)` to `line.split(' ', 1)` and it worked.
It seems that the space is not clear, to be perfectly clear: It should be `line.split('(one space here)', 1)`.

Comment: It seems that the space is not clear, it should be line.split('(one space here)', 1)